# Binding List into View Model and Iterate through ir on View

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I am doing MVC, I have view Models like this

```
  public class TaskViewModel
{
    public List<TaskProduct1> TaskProduct1{ get; set; };
    public List<TaskProduct2> TaskProduct2{ get; set; };
}
```

Now I want to access these view model in my view

I have used this line at the beginning of the view

```
 @model TotalTask.Models.TaskViewModel
```

but when I want to iterate through the list I can not access them

```
  @foreach (var item in Model) //Model.TaskProduct1 won't show Up here
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Subject
            </td>
           
            <td >
                @item.EndDate
            </td>
            
        </tr>
    }
```

how can I iterate through  List TaskProduct1  in view ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.TaskProduct1.Id
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.TaskProduct2.Subject
        </td>
       
        <td >
            @item.TaskProduct2.EndDate
        </td>
        
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: item.TaskProduct1.Id, item.TaskProduct2.Subject,.... are not accessable

Comment: @Düzgün Emre Özkan - Please be sure to explain your code when supplying an answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You should changed your iterator to be on Model.TaskProduct1 as follows:
@foreach (var item in Model.**TaskProduct1**)

Comment: when I type Model.   The taskProduct1 won't show up

Comment: Could be related to vs intellisense, even if it's now showing ,try it and run the app.  does it work ?

Comment: Any Explanation? @AnasGhanem

Comment: @AhmedAli, The OP wanted to iterate over the TaskProduct1 list , not the root model, so the correct way is as I wrote to him above, to iterate over the Model.TaskProduct1 list.

Comment: Yes, you should add this to your answer.